# docker, duel flask, ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, docker, flask

long time listener, first time caller.

I have been trying to figure this out myself and I have come up a bit stuck, there are plenty of examples around and explanations a plenty most seem to just move the package up to encompass all the modules, but I think dockerizing complicates things a little, or perhaps I am?

My project has a few components Python/Flask, Docker (docker-compose), Mariadb. I am building a flask admin and flask api on top of a Mariadb data source. Initially I had docker-compose running flask, serving API and Admin in one package. I then came up with the bright idea of splitting the two services, and in the process wanted to reduce duplication of scripts such as my models and some shared configuration.

```
project
- api
--_init_.py
--...
- admin
--_init_.py
--...
- models
--_init_.py
--roles.py
--users.py
--...
- config
--_init_.py
--development.py
--...
Dockerfile-api
Dockerfile-admin
docker-compose.yml
requirements-api.txt
requirements.admin.txt
```

Now of course when I try to access models from admin.**init**.py I get the `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

I have come the conclusion from reading, that I might need to do something with pip to import the module models at the time the `requirements` are read, but would require docker-compose to update the containers each time the models are modified.

Now the question, any ideas, appreciated. Am I on the right track and can anyone share an example I can follow?

Admin and API **init**.py go something like this

```
import os

# Import installed packages
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
#from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_migrate import Migrate
#from flask_restx import Api, Resource, fields
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore

# Import app code
from admin.core.admin import configure_admin
from admin.core.db import db
import admin.core.models # Probably needed for flask-migrate

# Import models
from .. import models
#from ..models import Role, User  # Security models

# Initialise extensions
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__,instance_relative_config=True)
```

Cheers for the help.

Comment: show your import statement but the short answer is that `project` doesn't have an `__init__.py` file in it so you can't import from the other folders in `project`

Comment: I found a simple solution to this;
https://www.peterspython.com/en/blog/two-flask-apps-frontend-and-admin-on-one-domain-using-dispatchermiddleware